# Zeroing out one component of a vector that is in a convex set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contains zero.
Let $x \in C$ be a vector with $n$ components. Suppose we zero out one of its components. Without loss of generality, let that component be the first one, then $y=[0, x_2, \dots, x_n]^{\top}$. Is there a certain class of convex sets such that when $x \in C$ implies $y \in C$?

**My try**

Currently, I can think of a box that contains the zero vector, i.e., $C=[l_1,u_1]\times \dots \times [l_n, u_n]$, i.e., $l_i\leq 0 \leq u_i$ for all $i=1, \dots, n$. Also, pictorially I feel any symmetric set would do the same thing but I do not know how to show it.

**Question**

Are there any type of closed convex sets when $x \in C$ implies $y \in C$?

Comment: You are asking that the projection of $C$ onto the hyperplane $x_1=0$ should be contained in $C$. In other words the section of $C$ along $x_1=0$ is "thickest". What other kind of characterization are you interested in?

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek: Thank you for providing this great intuition. As $x_1$ may be chosen arbitrary, then (first question) do still box and symmetrical sets (in higher dimension) valid ones? (second question) I want convex sets that are represented nicely like polytopes and prove this property for them.

Comment: Other examples are ellipsoids whose axes coincide with the coordinate axes. But if the axes don't coincide, then even if it's centred on the origin, [it doesn't have your property](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x-y%29%5E2+%2B+3%28x%2By%29%5E2+%3D+1). So being symmetric, even about the origin, is not enough.